# The region where the two variable function $xy/(x-y)$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to found the area where this function is differentiable

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x-y} $$

How do I need to proceed?

For partial derivatives I got:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{-y^2}{(x-y)^2} \quad and \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2} $$

What i do next?

Comment: Your tag is incorrect. Edit with tag analysis.

Comment: Need to prove that each derivative is continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the function is defined on $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, x \neq y\}$. Prove that this set is open and that the partial derivatives exist and are continuous on this set. This gives that $f$ is differentiable on this set.

Comment: I put what i found for partial derivatives, what i do to proof that are continuous in this set?

Comment: @evandrobm you have to do nothing. The functions are ratios of polynomials, and polynomials are known to be continuous as elementary functions. Whenever you have a function that is the composition of elementary functions, you know that it is continuous where it is defined.

Comment: Yeah, but i believe that this exercise want me to prove that this it true

Comment: @evandrobm I do not believe so. Anyway, if that's what the exercise wants you to do, then you have to do some $\epsilon$-$\delta$ work.